# make Inner div has same height as Outer Div (P.S: Outer div has custom scrollbar)

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="outer" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:470px; width:900px;">
     <div id="inner" style="position:relative; width:900px; height:1000px;">
     </div>
</div>
```

A few more points, i have a custom vertical scroll bar for the inner Div, but the thing is that this scroll bar is not working unless i gave it a height value which is something i don't want because if more content was added, it will not be shown in the inner div.

P.S: if no height at all was given to the inner div, scroll bar won't works at all and only the content of 470px height (outer div height) would be shown.

I've been trying for a whole day to figure it out and coulden't so far.

Comment: the `#inner` div should not have height.. the problem lies with the custom scrollbar system you use.. what is it ?

Comment: if no height was given, it takes height as 0px, note that the inner div contain alot of divs, tables, etc..

Comment: What is the custom scroll bar code you are using?

Comment: If you have an absolutely positioned element inside a relatively positioned one, height:100% will (usually) be the same as the parent.  I say usually because there are a number of caveats.  You could also try height:auto on #inner.  But a more detailed example would be helpful...